# Why do I have the GoldenGate for PostgreSQL Error in ODBC?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, oracle-golden-gate

I have installed The GoldenGate for PosgreSQL with the specification ([the specification theme](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GIPSQ/setup.htm#GIPSQ124)). The specification for my error is fully small (see: [the specification theme](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GIPSQ/setup.htm#GIPSQ124)).  My error is:

```
GGSCI (quickstart.cloudera) 1> DBLOGIN SOURCEDB source USERID postgres
Password: 

2019-07-02 00:48:15  WARNING OGG-00552  Database operation failed: Couldn't connect to source. ODBC error: SQLSTATE IM002 native database error 0. [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini.
ERROR: Database operation failed: Couldn't connect to source. ODBC error: SQLSTATE IM002 native database error 0. [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini.Failed to open data source source for user postgres.
```

I have seen a specification and the google, I need a specialist.

My ODBC.ini file is:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
postgre=DataDirect 6.1 PostgreSQL Wire Protocol
[ODBC]
IANAAppCodePage=4
InstallDir=/usr/lib64/
[postgre]
Driver=/home/cloudera/gg/lib/GGpsql25.so
Description=DataDirect 6.1 PostgreSQL Wire Protocol
Database=source
HostName=quickstart.cloudera
PortNumber=5432
LogonID=postgres
Password=
```

I've set the $ODBCINI environment variable in OS in /etc/odbc.ini.

Why is the error arised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your database login command in ggsci cmdline is wrong:

> GGSCI (quickstart.cloudera) 1> DBLOGIN SOURCEDB **source** USERID postgres

here you should use the alias name in odbc.ini, not the actual DB name, in your file is "postgre", in line 6, so try this command:

> DBLOGIN SOURCEDB **postgre** USERID postgres

good luck! :)